# Excel Excluding Leading Zero in Number Column While Exporting Data To Excel C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void BTN_export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = (DataTable)(ViewState["allgrid"]);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView GRD = new GridView();
        GRD.DataSource = dt;
        GRD.DataBind();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GRD.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
        Session["id"] = null;
    }
}
```

While Exporting Excel, it Excludes Leading Zeros in One Column. Above is my Code For Exporting Excel

Comment: Make the column a `string` type so it is treated as text by Excel.

Comment: Your question is saying two things - Accepting Leading Zero and Excluding Leading Zero. Which one is it? Eitherway, your column has to be General or Text formatted, otherwise the numbers will naturally strip off leading zeros. You may need to also prefix the value with single quote char

Comment: Dear  Fernando68, appending single quote at the beginning works but it also shows the single quote in Excel. i don't want to Display single quote.

Comment: Dear CodingYoshi, can me provide me some example

Comment: If you store `00555` in a numeric `DataColumn`, the data stored in that column is `555`, that is the value the Excel recieves. If you store `00555` in a string `DataColumn`, the data stored is `00555` because is not converted to a number and the value the Excel receives is `00555`

Comment: Dear bradbury9, My Sql Data Type is Varchar

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.